# How to access thumbnail toolbar buttons?

Tags: python, windows, winapi

I'm trying to make some controls with apps (for example Discord or any app that has thumbnail toolbar buttons). I've already tried to google, search or just look at the docs. Is there any possible way to do that in python?

Screenshot of what I want to control:

[image: Screenshot of what I want to control.]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you looking for "Thumbnail Toolbars" ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/taskbar-extensions#thumbnail-toolbars If yes, AFAIK, this API is not currently accessible to python with standard win32 modules (unless you write a C++ extension module yourself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to access the toolbar and certainly not from another process.

You can however use something like Spy++ to find the button id in WM_COMMAND and then send a message yourself to perform a toolbar button click. This is of course application specific and the id could change if the application is updated.

> [When a thumbnail button is clicked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/brownfield/windows-7-taskbar-apis), the application receives a WM_COMMAND message with the high word of the wParam set to THBN_CLICKED and the low word set to the button ID. This message is dispatched to the window to which the thumbnail belongs.

Comment: Application updates is not the problem because I'm making it only for me, I just need to figure out how to do that in python because there are no any info about it.

Comment: You can call Windows API functions in Python. You probably want to call `FindWindow` + `PostMessage`.

Comment: I know about that, but the question is the following: what library and functions should I use? I can't find any understandable info, as I said before.

Comment: I told you which functions to use. If you don't know how then you need to research ctypes or PyWin32. Knowing how to call these functions is separate from your specific question...